# "TypeError: cannot create mpf from d"', when "For" structure is executed

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-math, mpmath

```
import sympy.printing as printing
from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex
from sympy import *
from mpmath import *
from sympy.codegen.ast import aug_assign, For

init_printing()

c, d, c_max, d_max, jzeros = symbols("c d c_max d_max jzeros")

c_max.subs(c_max, 3)
d_max.subs(d_max, 3)

For(d, Range(d_max.subs(d_max, 3)), [jzeros.subs(jzeros, besseljzero(d, c_max))])
```

Why do I get this error ("TypeError: cannot create mpf from d") when I execute the above code? How do I make this code work? I am trying to code according to this "For" documentation: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/codegen.html#sympy.codegen.ast.For

Comment: This is unrelated to the ``For``. It is just ``besseljzero(d, c_max)`` telling you that mixing a ``mpmath`` *evaluation* and ``sympy`` *variable* does not work.

Comment: How it should be? The code between [] is the code to be executed in For, right?

Comment: Yes, it is, but you are not supplying a (sympy) code object. You are executing ``besseljzero`` when constructing the list.

Comment: As sympy and mpmath can't be mixed (they don't understand about each other's functions and symbols), you'd create a terrible mess by importing everything (`import *`) from both together.

Comment: Also note that sympy symbols and expressions are immutable. A statement such as `c_max.subs(c_max, 3)` doesn't change `c_max`. It just evaluates to `3`, but nothing will happen with that value.  A statement such as `c_max = 3` will assign `3` to `c_max` and destroy the connection between `c_max` as variable and the sympy symbol with the same name.